# How do you update a ListBox with running processes in real-time?

Tags: .net, vb.net, tasklist

In Windows, the *Task Manager* updates itself automatically with all of the running processes on your *Laptop/Desktop*. However, that is ***not*** my point.

My question is, is there a way to update a ListBox (Preferably with `Timer1.Tick` due to my instance) with all new processes, but in real-time (updates to the new processes every set interval)?

I have my `ListBox1` filled with the currently running processes.

**Things I've Tried**

1. In my sub '`Timer1_Tick`', I've tried using the `ListBox1.Refresh()` code, but, I've realised, all that does is refresh the `ListBox`, ***not*** the running process.
2. Researching for similar questions

Code that gets the running processes

```
Private Sub Mainframe_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim procs() As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses
        Dim f As String

        For Each proc As System.Diagnostics.Process In procs
            f = GetProcessFileName(proc)
            If f.Length > 0 Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(f)
                ListBox1.Items.Add("MD5: " & GetMD5String(f)) <-- Not relevant
                ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Empty)
            End If

        Next

    End Sub
```

My `Timer1` code

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Enabled = False 'Stops the timer
    ListBox1.Update()
    ListBox1.Refresh()
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Before using `ListBox1.Refresh()`, make sure you've updated the list of process bound with the ListBox. (By the way, I suggest you to name correctly your listbox)

Comment: Yes, I do @Stefan

Comment: I'm just trying to explain what I'm trying to achieve. It may not sound relevant, but I just thought it might give a better understanding of the question. @Stefan

Comment: All good! I'll put the code in the question. @Stefan

Comment: Ok, done! @Stefan

Comment: Ok sure. @Stefan

Comment: If I add in the code from my `Mainframe_Load` sub, when I do `ListBox.Refresh(procs)` I get an error which says: "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Refresh' accepts this number of arguments." @Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head: it should be something like this.

Disclaimer: I speak not so good VB ;-)

PS: possibly you get a "not on the same thread invoke exception"

```
Private Sub Mainframe_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'call it initially
    RefreshList()
End Sub

'this sub actually does the lisbox update
Private Sub RefreshList()
    Dim procs() As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses
    Dim f As String

    'as from @Visual Vincent's comment:
    ListBox1.BeginUpdate()
    ListBox.Items.Clear()

    For Each proc As System.Diagnostics.Process In procs
        f = GetProcessFileName(proc)
        If f.Length > 0 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(f)
            ListBox1.Items.Add("MD5: " & GetMD5String(f)) <-- Not relevant
            ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Empty)
        End If

    Next

    ListBox1.EndUpdate()

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Enabled = False 'Stops the timer
    RefreshList()
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, testing it out now.

Comment: Works, just a little bit laggy. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome; yes, UI updates are in general a bit laggy. You can improve that, but that would require some tweaking. And is a whole different subject ;-)

Comment: And instead of `ListBox.Clear` it's `ListBox.Items.Clear` :-)

Comment: Good solution, but you might want to remove `ListBox1.Update()` and `ListBox1.Refresh()` as they now do unnecessary redraw of the list box _twice_. The control already redraws itself when you add items to it, so they're not necessary :). -- Another thing you can do to increase performance is to call `ListBox1.BeginUpdate()` before the loop and `ListBox1.EndUpdate()` after the loop. This will cause the list box to not redraw itself until `EndUpdate()` is called, otherwise it redraws itself every time you add an item.

Comment: @Sir.Price: tweaked it a bit conform VisualVincent's comment.